# Matrix multiplication in python use *

Tags: python, multiplication

I have some code here:

```
u = np.zeros((4, 1))
U = np.zeros((4, 4))
# Then did some stuff to change some value in U
X = U * u
print U
print u
print X
```

Output:

```
[[ 0. -1.  2.  0.]
[ 0.  0. -1.  3.]
[ 0.  0.  0. -1.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
[[ 0. -0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. -0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. -0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

I cannot figure out. Shouldn't X be 4 * 1 matrix? Why it is 4 * 4?

Comment: What's the type of those variables?

Comment: Why do you feel it should be 4 by 1?  You are creating `numpy` arrays, not `numpy` matrices.  Perhaps you could start by reading the documentation of the library you're using?

Comment: use `np.dot` for matrix multiplication, `*` is interpreted as element wise multiplication, and `u` is then broadcasted as a 4x4 array (4 replicas of `u`)

Comment: Elaborating on what @donkopotamus, multiplication of numpy arrays is done by broadcasting.  Use `dot` for matrix multiplication.  (In Python 3.5+, you can use `@`.)

Comment: I will look it up. Thank you.